# When to make class and function?

Tags: function, language-agnostic, programming-languages, class-design

I am a beginner to programming when I start to code I just start writing and solve the problem.
I write whole program in a single main function.
I don't know when to make class, and functions.

What are good books which I read to learn these concepts?

Comment: I know the question is language agnostic, but if you tell us what language you're using we might be able to help a little more.

Comment: This is (in my opinion) NOT a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474980/object-oriented-programming-looking-for-good-tutorials

Comment: i am talking about java language . i frequently use swing

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A very general question, so just a few rules of thumb:

- code reuse: when you have the same or very similar piece of code in two places, it should be moved to a function
- readibility: if a function spans more than a single page on screen, you may want to break it apart into several functions
- focus: every class or function should do only one specific task. Everything that is not core to this purpose should be delegated to other classes/functions.

Comment: +1: Especially for third point (which should be in bold IMHO) :)

Comment: Yeah.. I was gonna say that too. Emphasis on the 3rd point. Basically, if you can give a name to a few lines of code (describe what it does in about 3 words or less), then do it.

Answer (score 7):

I think the canonical answer here is that you should organize your code so that it's readable and maintainable. With that said, it's also important to consider the cost of organizing your code, and how long you expect your code to live.

More directly in response to your question: functions should be used to replace repetitive or otherwise well contained pieces of code. If you apply the same 10 operations over and over again on the same kinds of elements/data you might want to think about collecting all that information into a more concise and clear function. In general, a function needs well defined inputs and outputs.

Classes, in essence, collect functions and data together. Much like you should use a function to collect operations into concise, well defined collections of operations, classes should *organize* functions and data relevant to be stored together. That is, if you have a bunch of functions that operate on some things like a steering wheel, brakes, accelerators, etc. you should think about having a Vehicle class to organize these relevant functions and data/objects.

Beyond acting as an organizational element, classes should be used to enable easy reuse and creation of multiple "things" - suppose you wanted a collection of those Vehicles.  Classes allow you to tie meaning or at least some semantics to your program.

The point of all this, though, is to make your life and the lives of others easier hen it comes to authoring and maintaining your program. So, by all means, when you need a solution to a problem in less than ten minutes and you think it's a one-time use program, ignore all this if you think it'll let you accomplish what you need to faster. Bear in mind, all this organization, semantics and ease of repetitve operation exists to make it *easier* to accomplish your objectives.

Answer (score 2):

This is a stylistic and preference question and depending on how formal a place you work at it could be a matter of standards.  I follow a couple of rules.

- Classes

  - Sets of related data belong in classes together
  - Functions to operate on that data should be in the classes together 
               
     The classic Example is the Car class functions would be things like Drive and AddGass
- Functions

  - If you are going to use it more then once it should be in a function
  - Most functions should be no more then one screen of code
  - Functions Should do one thing well not a bunch of things poorly

there Are a ton of opinions, but over time you must develop your own style.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually very simple nicky!

The purpose of splitting code into methods is simply to allow its reuse.  When you create a method you allow your program to invoke it at any time from several places instead of repeating the code again and again.

So every time you write lines and think... 'hey, I might need this functionality again somewhere in my program', then you need to put it in a method.

As for classes, you will try to group similar functionalities together.  And try to keep classes short and simple.  If you need several classes, you'll also group them in packages and so on.

When I write code, I usually have a pretty good idea what I'll be using again.  But often I will start to write a few lines of code and realize that I wrote something quite similar in the past.  So I'll find it and put it in a method then the two or more locations can now just invoke it.  That is reuse at its best!

You can often use analyzers to find various metrics which will "put a grade" on your reuse and code duplication.

Happy learning!

Comment: "The purpose of splitting code into methods is simply to allow its reuse" <nitpick>Also aids testing, reduces cohesion, aids debugging (single point of failure), gives greater confidence that changes are localized when fixing/enhancing code . . . </nitpick> (I'm an incurable pedant, sorry)

Comment: Naw, you aren't being nitpicky. I'll 2nd you ;)

Comment: I never said it was THE ONLY REASON!!  Who are these idiots that downgrade answers like this!  Not useful?  Ya right!  My post is probably the best reason as to why you split your code.  What is this place?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

[Procedure, subroutine or function?](http://computerprogramming.suite101.com/article.cfm/procedure__subroutine_or_function_), [Object-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

> An object is actually a discrete
>   bundle of functions and procedures,
>   all relating to a particular
>   real-world concept such as a bank
>   account holder or hockey player in a
>   computer game. Other pieces of
>   software can access the object only by
>   calling its functions and procedures
>   that have been allowed to be called by
>   outsiders.

Basically, you use a function/procedure/method to encapsulate a specific section of code that does a specific job, or for reusibility.

Classes are used to encapsulate/represent an object with possibly its own data, and specific function/procedure/method that makes sense to use with this object.

In some languages classes can be made static, with static function/procedure/method which can then be used as helper function/procedure/method

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, it'll become more evident when and why functions are useful as you progress to larger projects. I was a bit confused by their use when I first started too, when your entire program is only 20-50 lines of code which follows a very linear path, they don't make much sense. But when you start re-using tidbits of code, it makes sense to throw it in functions. Also makes it easier to read and follow the logic of your program if you only have to read descriptive function names, rather than deciphering what the next 5 lines of code are supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself asking this same question, and it led me to this post.

I think that one of the most confusing things about how OOP is explained to beginners is the idea that classes represent exactly what they sound like: classes of things, like Computer, Dog, Car, etc.

This is fine as far as it goes, but it's not strictly true, and the reality is much more abstract. Sometimes, classes don't really represent anything that could be considered a clearly defined abstraction of a group of things. Sometimes, they just organize stuff.

For this reason, I think "class" is really a misnomer, or at least misleading. A more relatable way to think about what a class is might be to simply think of it as a "group" or a "logical grouping."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).