# When do I need to start grouping my functions into classes?

Tags: python, function, class, principles

I have a python script that has has a few nested menus and I want to ask if it is better if I group the individual functions together into classes. I have a main menu with two sub menus and each sub menu has another sub menu. The code is in this link: https://github.com/mangoomeh/clashRoyaleClanManager/blob/master/clash.py

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. This question is both primarily opinion-based and too broad.

Comment: See [When to make class and function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301325/when-to-make-class-and-function)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: OOP is not about grouping functions into classes. It is more about how you think about the problem in terms of objects and their relationships. Classes are just like descriptions for the objects you decide to use.